Issue with Claiming 375AI Token
I hope this message finds you well. I am writing to seek assistance regarding an issue I encountered while trying to claim the 375AI token. I have 20 SOL in my wallet, but when the transaction pop-up appears, it says I do not have enough tokens. Could you please provide a solution to rectify this issue?
Thank you for your prompt attention to this matter.
